# Trying to pass Guid parameter in HTML.ActionLink but getting ?Length=5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, parameter-passing, actionlink

I'm trying to pass a parameter via a URL.

I'm passing a Guid in my URL:

```
http://localhost:55097/Admin/ListCase/a2cc5900-bdff-41f1-9c2a-21032a5275de
```

And am trying to capture it in the next view and add it to another URL as a parameter:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add a Cover","CreateCover","Admin", new { id=Request.QueryString[0]})
```

I've tried to bass it as a ViewBag and grab it from QuesryString (like shown above), but or some reason the resulting link comes out with ?Length=5 at the end. Not the Guid.

Any ideas???

Comment: the first one is not a query string value, it is a url segment.  putting a `?` in front of the GUID would make it a query string value.

Answer (score 0):

As @ps2goat says, the way you have the URL constructed makes the GUID part of the path, not the query string.  You also might want to give it a key for identification:

```
http://localhost:55097/Admin/ListCase/?guid=a2cc5900-bdff-41f1-9c2a-21032a5275de
```

Then you can retrieve it using the "guid" key:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add a Cover","CreateCover","Admin", new { id=Request.QueryString["guid"]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your action link to the other overload method and get the id parameter from the route data collection rather from query string as,

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add a Cover","CreateCover", routeValues: new { controller = "Admin", id= Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]})
```